# Getting error while placing order in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, sales-order, place-order

I'm getting intermittent error while placing order. I'm trying to add a Configurable product along with bundle product and a simple product.
While adding the above same product around 10 times and placing the order 10 times, I get below error around 4-6 times and rest of the time the order gets placed without any error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Type::getConfigurableAttributeCollection() in /var/www/html/Magento/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Helper/Product/Options/Loader.php:52 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/Magento/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/Product/ReadHandler.php(48): Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Helper\Product\Options\Loader->load(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor)) #1 /var/www/html/Magento/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/Operation/Read/ReadExtensions.php(48): Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\ReadHandler->execute(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), Array) #2 /var/www/html/Magento/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/Operation/Read.php(117): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\Read\ReadExtensions->execute(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), Array) #3 /var/www/html/Magento/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/EntityManager.php(61): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\Read in /var/www/html/Magento/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Helper/Product/Options/Loader.php on line 52
```

Comment: I also have the same issue. 2.1.6 EE